# How do i discard certain files (that arent conflicted) during a merge with Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using SmartGit and changed over to Sourcetree.

In SmartGit, when clicking on Merge it presents a preview list of files with changes to merge before actually doing the merge. From there I would be able to select files I do not want to merge by "discarding" them, e.g. files that are specific to development environment or irrelevant files. After discarding these files, only then I will proceed with the merge. Also a future merge would exclude these discarded files as well from even showing up in the merge preview.

However in Sourcetree when I right click merge on another branch, it is merged immediately if there are no conflicts in the merge. There is no preview and seems to be no way to discard certain files from being included in the merge. I would have to discard the changes by doing a revert on those files in a second commit. That seems like an unnecessary step.

Is there a better way of getting a preview of the changes to be merged and discard those I don't want in Sourcetree before it is actually merged ?

#### Update

I found out I can run this command in terminal to have it start the merge but not actually commit so that I can discard unwanted files in the "file status".

`git merge --no-ff --no-commit $SOURCE_BRANCH`

Is there a UI option in Sourcetree to do the above?

Comment: In git? I don't think so... just in case, there is no need to have a second commit to get the files back. You can, after you do the first commit, get the files the way you want them to be and then add to index and runt `git commit --amend` so that you get that on the _merge commit_ itself.

Comment: `git merge --no-commit` + `gιt checkout HEAD files` + `git merge --continue` (or `git commit`).

Comment: In sourcetree can we have a preview of the merge before it actually merges so we can choose what files to go ahead with the merge?